# Turning a ResultSet into 2DArray/HashMap/Lists of Lists

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist, resultset

I think I've become code-blind.

I'm currently doing a small project with a friend and we're using JDBC to select from a mySQL database.

What I want is that after running the select statement, I get some sort of '2D' list of all the data back.

I think I want something returned like this -
`array[columnName][all of the data inside the selected column]`

---

*Pseudo Code*

```
        // Count all rows from a column 
        // Count the columns selected

        // Adds the column names to 'array'
        for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
            columns.add(resultSetMeta.getColumnName(i));

        // Adds the results of the first column to the 'array'
        // How can I add the results from n columns?
        for(int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++ ) {
            while (resultSet.next())
                rows.add(resultSet.getString(i));
        }

        columnsAndRows.put(columns, rows);
```

---

1. **What is the most appropriate data type to use to 'replicate' a table - ArrayLists, Arrays, or HashMaps?**
2. **What's the best way of making a `ResultSet` into a 2D datatype?**
3. **When iterating through a `ResultSet`, how can I move to the next column?**

Comment: If you want to have all the column data underneath each column name then a `Map<String, List<Object>>` would work. This means that you can only loop column by column however. Tables usually work row by row. So maybe a `List<Map<String, Object>>` would be more appropriate. For the most usable solution I would use a [Guava `Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use hashmap for key value pairs, where as key you put your resultset metadata and values as resultset values.

```
HashMap<String, Object> p = new HashMap<String, Object>();
p.put("ResultSetkey1","ResultSetvalue1");
p.put("ResultSetkey2","ResultSetvalue2");
```

Also I would like to say use ResultsetUtils  [ResultsetUtils](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/dormant/scaffold/trunk/src/java/org/apache/commons/scaffold/sql/ResultSetUtils.java)